# Closing multiple toplevels in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

I have created a tkinter application where the user can make multiple toplevel windows and have the option of closing them from inside the toplevel. I would like to make a button on the main window that closes all toplevel windows. How would I do this? Is there a way to do this without lists? If these toplevels are parts of classes is there also a way to call a function present in all of them?

Comment: _"Is there a way to do this without lists? "_ - why don't you want to use lists?

Comment: Because I just don't want to have to set up another list system for a while. I've set up tons of them and I just am burnt out with lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do the first part of your question about making a button in the main window to delete all the `Toplevel`s without making a list of them. This works by using the universal [`winfo_children()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) widget method to find all the child widgets of the root (main) window.

It's unclear to me what you meant about calling a function present in all of them — [`Toplevel`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/toplevel.html) widgets are instances of a predefined `tkinter` class which supports a predefined set of methods — and you can call them the same way the sample code below does with `child.destroy()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Main')
root.geometry('200x100')

def close_all(master):
    for child in master.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(child, tk.Toplevel):
            child.destroy()  # Call method.

button = tk.Button(root, text=f"Close Toplevels",
                   command=lambda master=root: close_all(master))
button.pack()

for i in reversed(range(4)):  # Create them bottom to top.
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel()
    toplevel.title(f'Toplevel {i+1}')
    toplevel.geometry('200x75')
    toplevel.lift()

    button = tk.Button(toplevel, text="Close me", command=toplevel.destroy)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```